# click image and have it to send data to view.py django

Tags: python, html, django, image, django-views

**this is my img in my two.html**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhKlz.png

`<td> <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/imageAll/101.png" width="100"; height="300"> </td>`

**i want to send data = 101 to my view.py** when i click in my img

because i want to use data.
how i can do in django. i have to tried in onclick but is not work.

**view.py**

```
def two(request):
    return  render(request,'two.html')
 def add(request):
    x =request.GET['name'] 
    Name = obj.Name
    return render(request,'show.html',{"name" : Name}
```

**urls.py**

```
    path('two/',views.two),
    path('add',views.add),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it this way
in your urls.py

```
from .views import PageView

urlpatterns = [
...
    path('images/<id_image:int>/', PageView.as_view(), name="image-view"),
...    
]
```

in your views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

```
class PageView(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        template_name = "template_{}.html".format(self.kwargs["id_image"])
        return [template_name]
```

in your html file

```
<a href="{% url "image-view" 1 %}">image 1 url</a>
<a href="{% url "image-view" 2 %}">image 2 url</a>
```

but probably you don't need to access to different templates (template_1.html, template_2.html,...)
if you have similar html files with different data, depending on your models value, then you better use DetailView you can read about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/